# Is Uri.encode() in Android equivalent to encodeURIComponent() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, encoding

I was trying to clarify difference between Java's `URLEncoder.encode()`, Javascript's `encodeURI()`, `encodeURIComponent()`, and Android's `Uri.encode()`.

It looks like this:

- Alphabets and numbers

  - Everyone keeps
- .-*_

  - Everyone keeps
- !~'()

  - `URLEncoder.encode()` encodes, others keep
- ,/?:@&=+$#

  - `encodeURI()` keeps, others encode
- Space

  - `+` for `URLEncoder.encode()`, `%20` for others

It seems like `URLEncoder.encode()` and `encodeURIComponent()` behaves the same. Am I correct, or in fact they also have some difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interesting question. I just ran some code to test this:

### [Javascript encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except:
>
> Not Escaped: `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`

**Code:**

```
var sb = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode(i));
    if (encoded.indexOf('%') !== 0 && !encoded.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
        sb.push(encoded);
    }
}
console.log(sb.join(' '));
```

**Result:**

```
! ' ( ) * - . _ ~
```

### [Javascript encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

> encodeURI escapes all characters except:
>
> Not Escaped: `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) ; , / ? : @ & = + $ #`

**Code:**

```
var sb = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    var encoded = encodeURI(String.fromCharCode(i));
    if (encoded.indexOf('%') !== 0 && !encoded.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
        sb.push(encoded);
    }
}
console.log(sb.join(' '));
```

**Result:**

```
! # $ & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; = ? @ _ ~
```

### [Java URLEncoder.encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Translates a string into application/x-www-form-urlencoded format using a specific encoding scheme. This method uses the supplied encoding scheme to obtain the bytes for unsafe characters.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
            String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf((char) i), "UTF-8");
            if (!encoded.startsWith("%") && !encoded.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) {
                sb.append(' ').append(encoded);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.substring(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

**Result:**

Note that + is actually a whitespace.

```
+ * - . _
```

### [Android Uri.encode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String))

> Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets using the UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers ("0-9"), and unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact. Encodes all other characters.

**Code:**

```
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        String encoded = Uri.encode(String.valueOf((char) i));
        if (!encoded.startsWith("%") && !encoded.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")) {
            sb.append(' ').append(encoded);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.substring(1));
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

**Result:**

```
! ' ( ) * - . _ ~
```

Comment: So the equivalent of `encodeURIComponent()` is Android's `Uri.encode()`, right?

Comment: Yes, I added documentation to the answer. They both encode all characters except for a certain list, which is equivalent for both functions.